# Expecting union: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException

Tags: scala, flink-streaming, avro4s

I have a avro schema as below:

```
{
  "name": "track",
  "namespace": "com.company",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "default": null,
      "doc": "The user anonymous Id",
      "name": "anonymous_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
      "default": null,
      "name": "properties",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "fields": [
            {
              "aliases": [
                "accountType"
              ],
              "default": null,
              "name": "account_type",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "name": "properties",
          "type": "record"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and for above avro I have case class defined as below.

```scala
case class Track(
  anonymous_id: Option[String],
  properties: Option[Properties]
)
    
case class Properties(account_type: Option[String])
```

and when I am deserialising the avro as below:

```scala
val trackData = AvroInputStream.binary[Track](eventValue, schema)
```

it is throwing the below error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found com.company.properties, expecting union
```

I have tried with `Either` data type but it is throwing the same error! Not sure what union here means in terms of Scala case class.

Comment: Can you validate the schema you have shared here is valid Avro? It looks like maybe some curly braces are misplaced or missing.

Answer (score 0):

looks like problem with namespaces in nested schemas. Here is ticket (for Hive but that good man is claiming it is Avro bug) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15316. I'm working on it too, and going to add namespaces in nested schemas.